How to attatch files with Chinese name by "attatchfile2" in LaTeX?
When including the 中文.docx， the file can be shown in pdf but can't be opened.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage[xetex]{attachfile2}
\begin{document}
\textattachfile[ucfilespec={./files/中文.docx}]{``./files/中文.docx''}{view source code}
\end{document}


What is the problem and how to fix it?

Try this patch. And do not add quotes around the files name. It also doesn't make much sense to add a path to the ucfilespec. The files are embedded in the PDF so their original folder is not relevant.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{attachfile2}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\atfi@embedfile{\EdefEscapeString\atfi@FILE{\atfi@FILE}}{}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\textattachfile[ucfilespec={中文.docx}]{./files/中文.docx}{view source code}
\end{document}


Yes. This way works.
